# DJI M600Pro Simulator ROS - geofenced?

Tags: ros, dji-sdk

I'm controlling a M600Pro using Robot Operating System. For some reason the simulator refuses to move past +-20 meters from takeoff. I've encountered this before and it ended with the damn thing crashing because behavior in real life was nothing like it.

Is there some stupid, invisible geofence, or is this a bug that has survived for a year?

I've used the same code as I used on m100, and just to double check I reproduced the error with DJI's own demo examples (demo_local_position_control - just added a zero to the targets).

And just to be clear, it works as expected within this fence. Flight status and display status are not changing and no warnings come.

EDIT: There was indeed a stupid invisible geofence, triggered by not being connected to the app. I do not know if it could be solved by not using controller at all, but if you use a controller and don't have it connected, 30 meters is what you get.

Comment: I recommend, in simulation, making a bag file and triggering the scenario. Then you can replay it, slow it down to the messages where it triggers, and even step through the code at that point (using gdb or so).

Answer (score 0):

Have you open the remote controller？When you turn off the remote controller，the drone can't fly exceed 50-meter hight and 30-meter distance.

Answer (score 0):

In DJI GO app that connected to the controller, there is a range and altitude limit in one of the tab. Just remove it then it will allow you to freely move around. My pilot turns that on before without me knowing it. In the end, took me a day to find out